# how to fix twilio-php uncaught exception on lookup of bad number?

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I'm weak on how throwing exceptions works...

I'm getting the following when entering a bad number in lookup:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Services_Twilio_RestException' with message 'The requested resource /PhoneNumbers/310-69-5340 was not found' in /home/jimbursch/includes/twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php:297 Stack trace: #0 /home/jimbursch/includes/twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php(265): Base_Services_Twilio->_processResponse(Array) #1 /home/jimbursch/includes/twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php(236): Base_Services_Twilio->_makeIdempotentRequest(Array, '/v1/PhoneNumber...', 1) #2 /home/jimbursch/includes/twilio-php/Services/Twilio/InstanceResource.php(79): Base_Services_Twilio->retrieveData('/v1/PhoneNumber...') #3 /home/jimbursch/includes/site_functions.php(655): Services_Twilio_InstanceResource->__get('phone_number') #4 /home/jimbursch/includes/admin/misc.php(43): lookupPhone('310-69-5340')

Here is where I believe it is happening:

```
private function _processResponse($response)
{
    list($status, $headers, $body) = $response;
    if ($status === 204) {
        return true;
    }
    $decoded = json_decode($body);
    if ($decoded === null) {
        throw new Services_Twilio_RestException(
            $status,
            'Could not decode response body as JSON. ' .
            'This likely indicates a 500 server error'
        );
    }
    if (200 <= $status && $status < 300) {
        $this->last_response = $decoded;
        return $decoded;
    }
    throw new Services_Twilio_RestException(
        $status,
        isset($decoded->message) ? $decoded->message : '',
        isset($decoded->code) ? $decoded->code : null,
        isset($decoded->more_info) ? $decoded->more_info : null
    );
}
```

Comment: Could you share the code that you have written that is throwing the error, then I might be able to update it to help you catch the error?

Answer (score 3):

You have to `catch` that exception.

Rightfully, the [Twilio SDK](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php) throws an [exception](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) when something errors.

You would have to do something like the following:

```
<?php
...

try {
    //Your Twilio code you'd like to execute
} catch( Services_Twilio_RestException $e ) {
    echo $e->getMessage(); // Or maybe log it
    // Handle the fact that "The requested resource /PhoneNumbers/310-69-5340 was not found"
}
```

By catching the error message, you avoid the `Fatal error` and your script can continue working, allowing you to register that the operation failed (or reported something else useful back).